# Phabricator workflows

Tags: phabricator, maniphest

I recently downloaded Phabricator to use as my repository management tool, I am completely new to it, my issue is getting to grips with workflows . When I create a number of tasks, I can see them on the Maniphest workboard. This is great however, as I complete a task the state of the task is NOT reflected on the workboard.

I was expecting that as a task transitions from open,assigned,under test, QA Accpted, I would see these transitions automatically on the workboard.

Does anyone know how to configure a Phabricator project to do this?

I also am struggling with the columns on my workboard. I managed to create them following the transitions mentioned above, but I cannot delete them (even though I am logged in as an administrator)

I am not using a hosted service, this is purely an instance running on my personal machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first question, about having the task state being represented by which column the task of in automatically, it's unfortunately not something that is supported. See https://secure.phabricator.com/T6409.

You might be able to hack something up, but it would likely be fragile worth respect to upgrades of phabricator.

For the second question... Hm, god question, deleting the column doesn't seem to be possible, but you can hide it. Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

**Deleting workboard columns is not allowed.**

This appears to be a design decision: 
https://secure.phabricator.com/rPa823d143b40451b827d1fdfeb980c9d3320736d1

Related to:
https://secure.phabricator.com/T5342

Instead, columns can only be hidden. This apparently fixes tasks being orphaned when their assigned columns were deleted.
Hiding columns unfortunately results in a mess of hidden columns when they're shown.

Optimal solution as of now: **hide unwanted columns, and think very carefully about column names!**